# English my language--question about sentence/grammar

Tags: syntactic-analysis

"He said" is a simple statement.  What kind of statement is:  He said Mark didn't like Susan.  "He said" can be called a sentence.  So can "Mark didn't like Susan."  Yet this is neither a compound or complex sentence.  What is it called when two different subject/verbs are co-joined without a semi-colon or the usual and, or , but, yet, etc.

Comment: "He said" is not a complete sentence. "say" is a transitive verb, it needs an object.

Comment: Seconding Barmar's comment. _He said_ is fragment. _He said something_, for example, would be a complete sentence

Comment: In the traditional pedagogy I underwent in childhood this is a *complex* sentence, composed of an independent clause and a dependent clause. *He said*, incidentally, is not "sentence" or an indendent clause: *say*  requires either an object or a complement, so without the dependent clause it is incomplete.

Comment: Sometimes transitive verbs can be used without overt objects -- like "He ate."

Comment: The sentence 'He said Mark didn't like Susan" has the word 'that' understood, connecting the two clauses: "He said _that_ Mark didn't like Susan."

Answer (score 1):

Think of the sentence like this:

> He said **that** Mark didn't like Susan.

So it's actually a complex sentence.

The two sentences are identical except for their [complementizers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementizer). When you omit the "that", you're using the empty complementizer.

---

Note that you need to use an [agentive ambitransitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambitransitive_verb#Agentive) verb in your main clause if you want it to be grammatical without the other clause. Your main clause ("he said") by itself just seems awkward if not ungrammatical (although [say](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/say) can be used intransitively).

A better verb would be *noticed*:

> He noticed.
>   Mark didn't like Susan.
>   He noticed [that] Mark didn't like Susan.